vcpkg for pre-compiled binaries
Is it possible to create a vcpkg package from pre-built binaries in a way that cmake’s find_package can find it?
I packaged some binaries using:
file(INSTALL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib DESTINATION ${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR})
file(INSTALL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include DESTINATION ${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR})

However, this does not generate the cmake config files needed for “find_packake” to work.
Do I have to create the config files manually or is there a way that I can make vcpkg generate them?

So you are creating your own port in vcpkg in an overlay?? I ask because vcpkg normally creates the config files when you install a port using vcpkg install nameOfPort

Yes. I’m creating my own port.
